# Propel how make many to many query "OR" both tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm, propel

I'm using propel ORM and have two tables:

```
offer
    id | description | ....
tag
    id | Name | ....
offer_tag
    offerid | tagid
```

where `offer_tag` is the many two many table and both columns are related to respective table id primary keys.

My goal is create a query, via PROPEL, that search a `word` that could be or in offer.description or in tag.name.
That is: if I search `eggs`, I could receive all offers that have `eggs` in offer.description but not in tag.name or that have `eggs` in tag.name but in offer.description, or in both tables column.

Someone could help me please?

Comment: This sentence makes no sense: *...where offer_tag is the many two many table and both columns are related to respective table id primary keys.*

Comment: @AMACB ORM is a terrible anti-pattern, that offends the essence of OOP. Given the circumstances, you expect ORM users to make sense?

Comment: thanks for comments... but PROPEL isn't my choiche... I have to manage a project where previous developer's work is based on this ORM. For me is frustrating, but this is the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

suppose I wanna search the word `milk`, that could be a tag, or in offer (product) description... the code is:

```
$of = OfferQuery::create()
                  ->where('Offer.Description LIKE ? %milk%')
                  ->or()
                     ->useOfferTagQuery()
                        ->useTagQuery()
                            ->filterByName('milk')
                        ->endUse()
                    ->endUse();
                  ->find();
```

This code find only offers (products) that have at least a relation in many to many table (offer_tag) and matching tag or description.
If there's a `offer` whose description contains `milk` but without tag, this offer will be excluded from query.

Hope could help someone.